# Find the limit of the sequence $\frac{n!}{2^n}$ as n tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We've only been taught to find limits using the Squeeze Theorem and L'Hopitals Rule, so I'm not sure how to go about finding the limit of this sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simpler idea, note that $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}2$$

It follows that $a_{n+1}/a_n>2$ for $n=3,4,\dots$ so that $a_n$ grows faster than $2^n$; thus it diverges to $+\infty$.

---

**Hint**  Set $$a_n=\frac{n!}{ 2^n}$$ and show that $a_n$ is strictly increasing for $n\geq 3$. That is, look at when $${a_{n+1}}>{a_n}$$ is true.

$2^n$ is tiny compared to $n!$ since we're multiplying by a constant factor of $2$, while in $n!$ we're constantly increasing the factor by $1$.

**LEMMA** $$n!/2^{n-1}$$ is a (positive) integer for infinitely many values of $n$.

**P** Take $n=2^k$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$. The multiplicity for which $2$ divides $2^k!$ is $$v_2(2^k)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left\lfloor \frac{2^k}{2^m}\right\rfloor\\=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\lfloor 2^{k-m}\rfloor\\=\sum_{m=1}^k 2^{k-m}=1+2+\cdots+2^{k-1}=2^k-1$$

which means $2^{2^k-1}\mid 2^k!$.

**SPOILER**

> You should be able to show that $$a_n\to +\infty$$

Comment: Note that being strictly increasing is not sufficient to conclude (the true assertion in your spoiler).

Comment: @GregMartin For infinitely many $n$s, $$n!/2^{n-1}$$ is an integer. I guess that does it.

Comment: True. Probably worth adding that (with a proof) to your answer.

Comment: @GregMartin I added a proof.

Answer (score 6):

$\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}}=1\cdot\frac{2}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdots\frac{n}{2}>\frac{n}{2}\rightarrow\infty$